# regex for .aspx? to modify query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to modify the query string,

from:   `http://server/test/default.aspx`
to:   `http://server/test/default.aspx?videoplay=20`

or

from  :   `http://server/test/default.aspx?toolPlay=1233136844420765`
to    :   `http://server/test/default.aspx?videoplay=20&toolPlay=1233136844420765`

ie. add `videoplay=20&` in between the query string

through jQuery. I have tried the `.replace` function but there is problem - I cannot find the correct regex. Can anyone provide a better approach or provide a regex for ".aspx?"

Comment: Any reason you're not just adding the `&videoplay=20` to the end of the URL?

Comment: Just append it to the url.  the order doesn't matter, so just add it to the end.  What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 2):

Well, what I would do is this:

```
if (url.indexOf('?') != -1) { 
    url += "&videoplay=20";
} else {
    url += "?videoplay=20";
}
```

It doesn't use a regex, and it handles the case where the url does not contain a query string already.

Comment: hey thanks for your concern ... bt in my case there is some scenario in which url does not contain *?* then this approach fails

Comment: @Ishaan: How do you figure?  It looks for a literal `?` in the string.  if it's there, it appends `&`.  If it's not, it appends `?` instead.  Can you show an example of it failing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape both the `.` and the `?` as they are special regex characters:

```
\.aspx\?
```

However, you can simply append `&videoplay=20` to the end of the URL. The effect will be the same, unless the serverside code is looking at the index of querystring variables (which is very poor practice).

Comment: thanks Oded this works ... well I am not appending **&videoplay=20** rather I am replacing **.aspx?** with **.aspx?videoplay=20&**